# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces Does Not Return the Interface of our Bluetooth Device

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

When our program reaches this for loop, SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces returns false instantly, thus never running through the for loop.  This tells us that SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces is not finding the interface of our bluetooth device, even though we checked that our device was paired to our computer through the app Bluetooth LE Explorer.  We already checked that AGuid is the correct UUID for our device.  We are using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 with BluetoothApis.h.  How do we get SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces to return the interface for our device?

HANDLE GetBLEHandle(__in GUID AGuid)

{

```
HDEVINFO hDI;

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA did;

SP_DEVINFO_DATA dd;

GUID BluetoothInterfaceGUID = AGuid;

HANDLE hComm = NULL;


hDI = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

if (hDI == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return NULL;

did.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

dd.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);



for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDI, NULL, &BluetoothInterfaceGUID, i, &did); i++) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you have the wrong GUID
I have the same problem.

I pointed out the GUID of the class and not the interface.
I used **{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}**

But but I need
**{0850302A-B344-4fda-9BE9-90576B8D46F0}**

Try this:)

Comment: Yes, you were right about it being the wrong GUID.  We solved our problem when we used the Service GUID of the service we were trying to subscribe to.  We found the Service GUID by connecting with the Bluetooth LE Explorer App in the Windows Store and copied that GUID into our code.

Comment: this comment has helped me finally enumerate interfaces. what i don't get it how we're supposed to do it without using that app to first get the service guid